# Python random generator odds different to calculated odds

Tags: python, random

I have an exercise to simulate a lottery (4 balls drawn from 45). I randomly generated a list of four numbers then iteratively compare it to further randomly generated sets of 4. This seems to work though the number of attempts to get a match is generally in the 10's-100's of thousands yet the odds of matching 4/45 should be closer to 1 in 5000. As I compare my lists as sets, the order shouldn't matter so I am stumped as to why the odds are so low compared to the "theoretical". I have run it dozens of times and always with the same output. I am new to Python so am guessing there is a basic error here, but any insight would be helpful.

```
import random

def comparator(x,y):
    counter = 1
    while set(x) != set(y):
        y = random.sample(range(1,46),4)
        if set(x) == set(y):
            print x,y
            return counter
        else:
            counter +=1


#call the function 5 times 
for i in range(1,6):
    selection = random.sample(range(1,46),4)
    draw = []
    output = comparator(selection,draw)
    print "Iteration %d = %d attempts" %(i,output)
```

Comment: You reuse the parameter `y` here, I think you should pass the sample size then create an entirely new variable to store the actual random sample in. Also please fix your indentation, as it stands it looks like the while loop is not indented properly

Comment: How did you calculate 1/5000 ?

Comment: The odds of you getting a win is `(4/45 * 3/45 * 2/45 * 1/45)` or `(1/45)^4
 * 4!` I believe, which would explain why it runs for so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a math question. The odds of getting it right are actually one to:

```
math.factorial(46)/math.factorial(4)/math.factorial(46-4)
```

which is 1 to:

```
163185.0
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics

You actually stop at first success so your measurement is somewhat biased.

Comment: Yes you are correct - thanks for pointing out this stupid mistake in my math. The 1:5000 came from a 6 ball draw where the denominator is 6!. Hence, the script is generating the "correct" odds for a 4 ball draw. I have now fixed this to generate a 6 balls draw and now check if set(x) is a subset of set(y) rather than if is is equivalent. Indention has been corrected so doesnt stop at first success. Sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Check your math.  The way I worked out the probability, it comes out to 1 in 45*44*43*42 / 4! = 148,995.  The numerator is because you are sampling without replacement and therefore, after the first number is picked, the odds of matching the subsequent one becomes 1/(n-1) and so on.  I divide by 4! because order does not matter and there are 4! ways to pick 4 numbers out of 45 without replacement.